# The graph of $f(x)$ lies below this line for small values of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose that there exists a function $f:\mathbb R_{+} \to \mathbb R_{+}$ with **only** the following properties  :

1. $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$
2. $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =0$

*My question:* Are $(1),(2)$ sufficient in order to deduce that $f(x) \leq 2x\;$ if $x$ is sufficiently small?

*My approach:* I tried with the standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, i.e
$\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \;\text{ such that } \; 0<x<\delta \implies f(x)<\epsilon\;.
\end{align}$ Then, choosing $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, I obtain that $f(x) <2\delta\;$ which then contradicts what I need to show. Does this mean that my question has a negative answer or am I missing something here?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn‘t $f(x)=3x$ already a counter example? It is bigger than 0 for all $x > 3$ and it approaches 0 as x approaches 0. And also it is never smaller than or equal to $2x$.

Comment: Good effort so far! Unfortunately when you know *there exists* a delta, that doesn't let you choose any old delta. Indeed the way you should approach this is to find a counterexample. In fact it's not even necessarily true that there is an $M > 0$ such that $f(x) \le Mx$ for $x$ sufficiently small (consider $\sqrt x$).

Comment: @JaMoin I suppose you mean that $f(x)>0$  for all $x>0$...You're right.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Your comment was really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou yeah that‘s what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

There is the counter example $f(x)=3x$, which satisfies both properties ($3x>0$ for every $x>0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} 3x =0$, because $f(0)=0$). It is also always bigger than $2x$.

The answer is that those properties aren‘t sufficient to deduce that $f(x) < 2x$ for sufficiently small values of x.